# Any side effects of changing the Xcode name in Applications folder?

Tags: ios, xcode

Are there any side effects of changing the Xcode application name from "Xcode" to for an example "Xcode 11.5" in the Applications folder?

Comment: Nope, It's just the name.

Comment: Simulators are not launching any more, even after deleting and creating a new one.